# Windows server 2016 Remote Desktop limited to 2 users

Tags: remote-desktop

I added the Remote Desktop licensing and installed 4 User CALs for remote desktop on a Windows 2016 server, stand alone not part of any Domain. 
rebooted system, still not allowing more than 2 users
Green checkmark on server name in RD Licensing Manager.

Any assistance on what to do next?

Mark

Comment: Have you installed the Remote Desktop Session Host role? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2833839/guidelines-for-installing-the-remote-desktop-session-host-role-service states that you must install both roles. P.s. the link provides the installation steps...

Answer (score 0):

Found that recommendation yesterday and installing Remote Desktop Session Host role did in fact solve my issue.

mark